# Function Combination on Computer Science

Tags: functions, logic, computer-science, contest-math, computability

I read some material on Computational Function, every one could describe the result of following combination?

suppose $g_1(x)=3x$, $g_2(x)=4x$, $f(x,y)=x+y$, how we compute combination of $f$ with $g_1$ and $g_2$?

i means the answer is :

h(x)=12x or h(x,y)=3x+4y or h(x)=7x or h(x,y)=12x^2 or sth else?

Comment: You seem to have some difficulty even to transcribe this question in a way that accurately communicates what you were asked to do. Perhaps it would be beneficial to take a photograph of the question in the exact form in which you received it, and post that here.

Comment: Maybe you mean composition? Something like $f(g_1(x),g_2(y))=3x+4y$?

Answer (score 1):

In [Computability Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_theory), a very important class of fucntions is the class of [Primitive recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function).

This class is defined starting form some initial (very "simple") functions and using few methods to build up new functions from already existing ones.

One of the methods allowed is that of *composition* [not "combination"] :

> Given $f$, a $k$-ary primitive recursive function, and $k$ $m$-ary primitive recursive functions $g_1, \ldots ,g_k$, the *composition* of $f$ with $g_1, \ldots ,g_k$, i.e. the $m$-ary function
>
> $h(x_1, \ldots , x_m) = f(g_1(x_1, \ldots , x_m), \ldots g_k(x_1, \ldots , x_m))$
>
> is primitive recursive.

In your example, we have $k=m=2$; $f(x,y)=x+y$ (the "sum" function) is *primitive recursive*; $g_1(x)=3x$, $g_2(x)=4x$ are p.r.

Thus, the *composition* of $f$ with $g_1$ and $g_2$ is :

> > $h(x,y)=f(g_1(x),g_2(y))=f(3x,4y)=3x+4y$.